# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Kategori

Tags: c#, properties, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a list that I want to add some data and then just write out on my console, but I got this error (The error is in the title). I know that there is something about my classes that isnt right.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Artikel
    {
        public string Artikelnummer { get; set; }
        public string Varonamn { get; set; }
        public string Beskrivning { get; set; }
        public string Bild { get; set; }
        public string Pris { get; set; }
        public Kategori kategori { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the class I am using to create my list. As you can see I have another class called **Kategori** and I've created a property of it. Now I want to use it in this list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Artikel> Minlista = new List<Artikel>();

        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Mjölk", Pris = "14.90", kategori ="", });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Apelsin", Pris = "7.90", kategori =  });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Skinka", Pris = "20", kategori = "", });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Räkost", Pris = "33", kategori = "", });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Köttfärs", Pris = "45", kategori = "", });
    }
}
```

}

When I try to add from list or set value it works fine untill I try on kategori. Why?
Oh and sorry also, I've writing the code using swedish words. hopefully it's not to hard to follow.`enter code here`

Comment: Your `kategori` property excepts the type of `Kategori` not `string`.

Comment: What is the definition of `Kategori`? It is a class? It is an enum? Please explain and add the definition to your code above

Comment: It's an class containing two propertys 

`code`    class Kategori
    {
        public string KategoriID { get; set; }
        public string Namn { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

The property called `kategori` is of type `Kategori` and not of `string`.

```
 public Kategori kategori { get; set; }
```

Hence you can't assign to the property `kategori` the value of a string. You should assign to `kategori`  an object of type `kategori`.

Answer (score 1):

Either change the type of `kategori` to be a string or the value you are assign to it:

```
class Artikel
{
    // ...
    public string kategori { get; set; }
}
```

or the assingment (for an empty value):

```
Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Mjölk", Pris = "14.90", kategori = null });
```

or for an "appropriate object":

```
Minlista.Add(new Artikel
    {
        Varonamn = "Mjölk",
        Pris = "14.90", 
        kategori = new Kategori() { KategoriID = "myID", Name = "myName" }
    });
```

*UPDATE as requested in comment:*
To loop over it and get the `kategori` you can do something like:

```
foreach (var article in Minlista)
{
    if (article.kategori != null)
        Console.WriteLine(article.kategori.Namn);
}
```

P.S - as you explicitly mentioned it: I always recommend to write code in english, even if you are just writing "some small tool for yourself". It's simply "best practice" which should be used/trained always IMO...

Comment: If I used the last example "appropriate object", can I do a foreach  from the list and figure out what's in the `kategori = new Kategori() { KategoriID = "myID", Name = "myName" }` cause that's what I need to do.

example if `KategoriID = "Meat"`I need to find from the list `Minlista`to see if the kategori is containing meat or not.

Answer (score 1):

If `kategori` is an instance of a class `Kategori` then you need to initialize it with an instance of the `Kategori` class, not with a string.

```
void Main()
{
    List<Artikel> Minlista = new List<Artikel>();
    Minlista.Add(new Artikel 
                     { Varonamn = "Mjölk", Pris = "14.90", 
                       kategori = new Kategori 
                       {KategoriID = "1", Namn = "Kategori Name"} 
                      });
}
```

If, at this point, you don't have a value for `kategori` then you simply leave it out from your initialization (and this means that the `kategori` field is left null)

```
Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Mjölk", Pris = "14.90", });
```